# Repair broken light connector on Volvo 240

Tags: electrical, volvo, lights, corrosion

So I tried to replace the broken [corner light assembly](http://www.eeuroparts.com/Parts/4141/Corner-Light-Assembly-Driver-Side-1312623/) on my '92 Volvo 240 last night.  On the old unit, the gray connector (pictured in link) was stuck, and eventually pulled free with part of the other side of the connector, as it was heavily corroded.

My question: **What is the best way to repair the broken wire/fitting/plug?**  I don't know if it's a standard connection type that I can buy at the hardware store, or if I'll need to buy another replacement part.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be great if you could you share a picture of the connector after taking it out

Answer (score 3):

The part image in the link shows three wires: green, white and black.

[image: part image]

Combining the image with [this blogpost](https://brickwalla.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/hard-wiring-my-tails/), which explains how to hardwire the 240 taillights, the green/blue is a signal wire for the turn indicator, black is ground. White is purportedly not used:

[image: taillight schematic]

---

### Options at your disposal

- Source the connector pair and solder/crimp them in place
- Hardwire the connection by crimping or soldering, eliminating the need for the grey connector altogether
- Replace with a generic connector that can be found at a regular electrical hardware store, similar to what has been described in the blogpost

If [this Volvo forum discussion](http://volvoforums.com/forum/volvo-240-740-940-12/tail-light-wiring-harnesses-25008/) is anything to go by, it's not uncommon to hardwire the lights up.

Comment: Zaid, thanks.  I'll point out that the lights are on the front, not the tail light unit - but I think you told me the reasonable options.